# How to Add all values given in comma separated in sql

Tags: sql

How to get the SUM of values of one column in table. Now I want get the SUM of 8 and 0 if I use query write below.

```
SELECT SUM(Items) FROM dbo.CustomSplit(@AssigneeProgress,',')
```

this gives an error

> *Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.*

My code is:

```
DECLARE @AssigneeProgress AS VARCHAR(100)

SELECT 
    @AssigneeProgress = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(ISNULL((((TblAssignments.PlannedDuration  * 100) / 300) * TblAssignments.Progress) / 100,0) AS VARCHAR(100)) 
                               FROM TblTasks,TblAssignments 
                               WHERE TblTasks.TaskId = TblAssignments.AssignmentEntityId 
                                 AND TblAssignments.AssignmentEntity = 'Task' 
                                 AND AssignmentStatus NOT IN ('Deleted','Cancelled') 
                                 AND TblTasks.TaskId = 63 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'')

SELECT * FROM dbo.CustomSplit(@AssigneeProgress,',')
```

This query gives me the result in table like

```
Items
8
0
```

Comment: The question is, why does your function return a varchar when indeed it should be an integer? You should really change that function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to cast the `Items` that you get back from your split function to an `INT` type before summing:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CAST(Items AS INT)) 
FROM 
    dbo.CustomSplit(@AssigneeProgress,',')
```

The `CustomSplit` function most likely returns `varchar(x)` items....

Answer (score 1):

Does your method CustomSplit return a table having the column Items of type varchar? 
If yes, you can convert the column:

```
SELECT SUM(cast(Items as int)) FROM dbo.CustomSplit(@AssigneeProgress,',')
```